# Live reload stopped working after Angular 8 update

Tags: angular, angular-cli

After upgrading Angular from 7 to 8, the live reload stopped working. Everything went well during the update and I have no compilation errors or anything.
Watch is also working as expected.

I tried with & without the `--live-reload` option. I tried with node version 10 & 12, same result.
I tried to follow the steps from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50867385/development-server-hot-updates-not-working) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40366212/angular-cli-ng-serve-livereload-not-working), same result.

```
Angular CLI: 8.3.2
Node: 10.16.3
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 8.2.4
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router, service-worker

Package                            Version
------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect          0.801.3
@angular-devkit/build-angular      0.801.3
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer    0.801.3
@angular-devkit/build-webpack      0.801.3
@angular-devkit/core               8.1.3
@angular-devkit/schematics         8.3.2 (cli-only)
@angular/cdk                       8.1.4
@angular/cli                       8.3.2 (cli-only)
@angular/material                  8.1.4
@angular/material-moment-adapter   8.1.4
@angular/pwa                       0.801.3
@ngtools/webpack                   8.1.3
@schematics/angular                8.3.2 (cli-only)
@schematics/update                 0.803.2 (cli-only)
rxjs                               6.5.2
typescript                         3.4.5
webpack                            4.35.2
```

I am also using Nx version `8.4.13`

Comment: Try updating your Angular CLI version `ng update @angular/cli`. `@angular/cli` and `@angular-devkit/core` and others should usually have the same version.

Comment: I aligned the versions, did not fix my problem but it is cleaner now :)

Comment: Angular Cli 8.3.2 is out. Why don't you update to the current version?

Comment: I updated to the highest version I could depending on my other dependencies ofc.

Comment: try `rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json yarn.lock` then `npm i` or `yarn` whatever you prefer

Comment: I worked! So it was a version misalignment/lock issue..
Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

In the end, aligning @angular libraries versions and a cleanup (`rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json`) fixed my issue!

Thanks a lot every body!