# How to resolve: "Definition for rule '@typescript-eslint/consistent-type-assertions' was not found"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, create-react-app, typescript-typings

My React app is not failing to compile due to the error: Definition for rule '@typescript-eslint/consistent-type-assertions' was not found

I'm kind of at a loss. I'm unable to find any current rule definitions in the project. The project was compiling initially. The error started after I restructured the app.

The app is failing to compile with error: Definition for rule '@typescript-eslint/consistent-type-assertions' was not found

packge.json -

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/react-dom": "16.9.0",
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.1.1",
    "styled-components": "^4.3.2",
    "typescript": "^3.5.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "PORT=3005 react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --transformIgnorePatterns",
    "e2e": "./node_modules/.bin/cypress open"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/dom": "^6.1.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.0.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.1.3",
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.18",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.137",
    "@types/node": "^12.7.2",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.2",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^4.3.4",
    "@types/styled-components": "^4.1.18",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "cypress": "^3.4.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Facing the same problem after upgrading dependencies

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My create-react-app is failing to compile due to ESLint error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64518226/my-create-react-app-is-failing-to-compile-due-to-eslint-error)

Answer (score 14):

Just update `react-scripts`. I solved it by uninstall and install again.
In command line:

uninstall:

```
npm uninstall react-scripts --save
```

and install again:

```
npm i react-scripts
```

Answer (score 11):

When I ran into this, I had created a brand new app using `create-react-app my-app --typescript` then copied the dependencies from another project that I had just finished. After messing around with things I noticed that the `react-scripts` was at version `3.1.1`, when I finally got this running again the working `package.json` had it at `3.1.2` looks like this is the culprit. A working `package.json` would look like:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "24.0.18",
    "@types/node": "12.7.5",
    "@types/react": "16.9.2",
    "@types/react-dom": "16.9.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.1.2",
    "typescript": "3.6.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Trying to get the error to disappear was a challenge, there is an evil bug in Visual Studio that will leave your `VSCompiler.exe` and other services hung up only using the version of the file that it had when the services hung up. No matter what you do nothing will work until you get these restarted, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50934814/1601882) on some tips how to resolve it, I realize it is for Angular but the same principles apply.

Answer (score 7):

I found a solution.
1) Delete the node_modules
2) update the Package.Json line of React-scripts to this: ""react-scripts": "3.1.2""
3) run npm i

This should work

Comment: No dice, unfortunately.

Comment: Strange!! this solved the issue for me. did you delete the node_module entirely before updating the package.json and running "npm i " again ?

Comment: Yes, I did. I took somewhat of the nuclear approach to resolving the issue. Luckily I had an earlier version of the project in git. I recloned the repo in a different directory and reinstalled the dependencies.

Comment: Yes! The app is compiling now.

Comment: Excellent. Glad to hear. I posted an issue in React's GitHub about this. Hope they will solve this soon :-)

Answer (score 4):

`yarn add -D @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@latest` or to be more precise `yarn add -D @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@^2`

I experienced the issue because the plugin was at `@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@^1`.

Answer (score 2):

1. In Package.json - Update version of react-scripts to  "react-scripts": "3.1.2"
2. npm install --save
3. npm start

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the problem by running `yarn install` again. If this doesn't work out, you can try to remove the node_modules folder completely and run `yarn install` again.

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered this exact error on a create-react-app git repository I cloned.  Running `npm install` followed by `npm start` gave me the same error message.

I then realised that the creator had been using yarn rather than npm.  So I deleted the repo, re-cloned it and ran `yarn install` followed by `yarn start`.  The error cleared.

This could be a npm vs yarn issue therefore.  Especially as create-react-app will [default to yarn](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/3974) if you have installed it previously; which might cause issues if you continue to use npm?  Appreciate this is a different circumstance as this is your own app, but it might be related.

Admittedly I ran straight into a different error, but at least I had made progress...

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the steps before, however, what actually solved my problem were these steps:

- 1.- Delete node_modules
- 2.- delete package-lock.json
- 3.- Update package.json line of React-scripts like this: "react-scripts": "3.1.2"
- 4.- npm install (or sudo npm install if you need further authorization).

I hope it helps somebody else.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I was supposed to use Yarn but instead I blindly use npm.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29943521)