# My create-react-app is failing to compile due to ESLint error

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I just created a fresh template with `create-react-app` with **react v17** included, and I installed eslint dependencies as I used to before, here's my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "gym-nation",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "axios": "^0.21.0",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-intl": "^5.8.6",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.1",
    "react-router": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-app-rewired start",
    "build": "react-app-rewired build",
    "test": "react-app-rewired test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.5.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.5.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^7.12.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.14.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^5.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^24.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.4",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.21.5",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-testing-library": "^3.9.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "prettier": "^2.1.2",
    "react-app-rewired": "^2.1.6"
  }
}
```

and here's my eslintrc.json: (note that i didn't add all the rules yet)

```
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es2021": true
  },
  "extends": ["react-app", "prettier"],
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    },
    "ecmaVersion": 12,
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "plugins": ["react", "prettier"],
  "rules": {
    "prettier/prettier": [
      "error",
      {
        "printWidth": 140,
        "singleQuote": true,
        "editor.formatOnSave": true,
        "arrowParens": "always",
        "jsxSingleQuote": true,
        "tabWidth": 2,
        "trailingComma": "none"
      }
    ],
    "no-unused-vars": "error"
  }
}
```

when I run the app will fail to compile due to this error:

```
Line 113:13:  'isLoading' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars
```

I've worked on previous projects and eslint errors were showing in the code without causing the app to crash. can anyone point where I messed up please?

Comment: Are you looking to correct the error or to change the `no-unused-vars` setting in your `eslintrc`?  Whichever you're attempting, what have you tried?

Comment: @David I tried the `warn` option for `no-unused-vars` in `eslintrc`  and everything worked fine but the problem is that now i can't see the linting errors in the code and i have to check the console every time i want to see them. i need to know why the app is crashing on eslint errors and how can i override it.

Comment: Here is the github ticket for this problem https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/10021

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @TimothyOliver yes, and I added it as answer to this question. thank you.

Comment: An update to latest version of craco solved this for me

Answer (score 107, accepted):

I have had the exact same errors when I created app using the `create-react-app` and **setup the eslint** for the application.

The eslint errors were showing up in the **browser** rather than in the **console**.

Once, I debugged all the dependencies. It seems that the `react-scripts` was causing the lint errors for me.

The newest version of the `react-scripts:"4.0.0"` may have some breaking changes which could be causing the eslint to throw the errors in the browser.

### **Solution:**

This issue has been fixed in the **`react-scipts:"4.0.3"`** but, the eslint  errors present in the project are **not converted to warnings by default**. You have to create an **.env file** which should contain a **`ESLINT_NO_DEV_ERRORS=true`** flag. Due to this flag, you will receive the **eslint errors as warnings** and **not as errors in the development**.

This **flag is ignored during production** and when they are any git hooks  running, which will in turn **cause an error** when you are trying to **commit the code** with an **eslint error in it**.

### **Update 2:**

Active Issue: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9887

**Workaround for this issue until react-scripts:4.0.2 is released:**

- Install **patch-package** and **postinstall-postinstall** as dev dependency .
- Go to **node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js** and make the following changes
  [image: Changes]
- Once done with the edit,run **yarn patch-package react-scripts**. This will create a **patches folder**, with the **dependency patch** in it.
- Now, as we **don't want do this every time** while installing the dependencies. We are going to **add another script** to our package.json file.

  `"postinstall":"patch-package"`.

> This above **script will run every time** when we install the dependencies. Just keep in mind that you will also have to **push packages folder** to your repo. If you need the changes, also while deploying the app.

Thanks to @fernandaad for providing this workaround.

### **Update 1:**

Had to downgrade to `react-scripts:3.4.4` version because there is no workaround available right now. Now, errors were being thrown in the console rather than in the browser.

1. Delete the node_modules and package.lock/yarn.lock.
2. Downgrade react-scripts from 4.0.0 to 3.4.4.
3. Install the dependencies and start the app.

Comment: I too have been unable to find a solution for this problem within v4.0 and so will be downgrading to a pre v4.0 version

Comment: It looks like the `eslint 7.0` used by `react-scripts:4.0.0` somehow enforces a stricter level of policy, throwing errors rather than warnings for certain plugins. For me it just would not work with `eslint-airbnb-base`, virtually blocking any compiling on even a tiny `no-unused-vars` mistake. Downgrading to `3.4.4` seems to be the only way without ejecting and customizing the webpack config to a deeper level

Comment: @GettingBetter This answer worked for me. https://stackoverflow.com/a/65216110/2573621

Comment: You're the GOAT! That environment variable simply just worked!

Comment: What a horrific bug this has been!!! Urgh!!

Comment: bug still exists with react-scripts 5.0. had to downgrade to 3.4.4

Answer (score 56):

I was able to fix it using env variables, since I'm not using webpack.

Make sure you're using the VSCode extension and that you installed eslint as a dev-dependency (as well as any other plugins you might need).

To get your code to lint, but not fail, in development, add this to your **.env.development**:
`ESLINT_NO_DEV_ERRORS=true`

To completely disable eslint on a production build, add this to your **.env.production**:
`DISABLE_ESLINT_PLUGIN=true`

After that, it should not fail any build. I don't understand why eslint should fail builds. It's there to help us keep code quality up, but not necessarily enforce it.

Comment: `ESLINT_NO_DEV_ERRORS=true` worked perfectly for me to continue developing without compilation failing due to lint errors. Thank you

Comment: worked perfectly, and also doesn't effect on the test!

Comment: The most elegant solution yet found

Answer (score 17):

it took me some hours to find possible solutions:

1- workaround:   add rules inside the *package.json* file

```
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": ["react-app"],
    "rules": {
      "no-unused-vars": "warn"
    },
    "overrides": [
      {
        "files": ["**/*.ts?(x)"],
        "rules": {
          "max-len": "warn"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
```

2- you can use a *.eslintrc.js* file, by adding *.env* file in the root folder with following content:

```
DISABLE_ESLINT_PLUGIN=true
ESLINT_NO_DEV_ERRORS=true
```

- DISABLE_ESLINT_PLUGIN- will disable [eslint-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/eslint-webpack-plugin) in the Development and    Production. - this is a must.
- ESLINT_NO_DEV_ERRORS - will convert ESLint errors to warnings during development. As a result, ESLint output will no longer appear in the error overlay.
  this alone won't fix the bug.

see also documentation [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/advanced-configuration/)
and [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/10170)

Answer (score 15):

## For [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/ignoring-eslint)

Open `next.config.js` and enable the `ignoreDuringBuilds` option in the eslint config:

```
module.exports = {
  eslint: {
    ignoreDuringBuilds: true
  }
}
```

Comment: this is gold, thanks!

Answer (score 11):

The developers around react-scripts decided to turn warnings into errors once `CI=true` is present. Therefore the only way to fix that is using `CI=false` for your command or make your eslint run warning free. There is no point to suggest eslint rules here cause yet another warning caused by your codebase or custom ruleset might trigger that issue.

Adjust your `scripts` block in `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "CI=false react-app-rewired start",
  "build": "CI=false react-app-rewired build",
  "test": "react-app-rewired test",
  "eject": "react-scripts eject"
}
```

Or run it that way:

```
CI=false npm run start
```

```
CI=false npm run build
```

See related issues on GitHub:

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/10062

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9887

Comment: I get "The term 'CI=false' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the 
name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again." with this solution.

Comment: Are you under Windows? You need to run "SET CI=false" then..

Comment: or "env CI=false" should be a cross platform option

Comment: There is a cross-env package for that... https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env

Answer (score 9):

This Compiled with problems can also solved to add this in the .env file.
I face the problem and try to solve it using this line of code.

## `SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true`

or

## `ESLINT_NO_DEV_ERRORS=true`

```
SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true or ESLINT_NO_DEV_ERRORS=true
```

---

or you can also edit package.json.

```
"start": "ESLINT_NO_DEV_ERRORS='true'  react-scripts start",  
"build": "DISABLE_ESLINT_PLUGIN='true' react-scripts build",
```

Answer (score 5):

For a temporary workaround, use `.eslintrc.js` so that you can check your current node environment and set rules accordingly. E.g:

```
const isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';
const warnDevErrorProd = isProd ? 2 : 1;

{
  ...
  "rules": {
    ...
    "prettier/prettier": warnDevErrorProd,
    "no-console": warnDevErrorProd,
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

This way you don't need to eject in order to modify your webpack config to change the rules there.

Answer (score 0):

When I upgraded my create-react-app to v4, it was intimidating to see pages of eslint issues -> errors preventing my app from compiling. Not the immediate experience I was expecting using react's `fast-refresh` :).  The change in rules (and error levels), in Eslint 7 are surely the cause. Although, how the transpiling process started to care about `prettier/prettier` issues that were previously limited to my linter, remains unclear to me.

#### Update

There are a few things going on.  The Eslint changes (and any extensions such as airbnb) are likely shaking up my mix of errors and warnings, but likely most relevant: CRA v4 no longer uses its own eslint rules, but rather that of the project, i.e., the linting rules used in my editor. Prior to the upgrade, CRA's use of the project rules was enabled using `EXTEND_ESLINT`.  This register is now *on by default* and no longer something I can set with `env` in v4 (in my experience anyway).

Regardless, the quick-fix to get the app to transpile was as follows:

1. `git commit` my latest changes
2. run prettier cli: `yarn prettier --config ./.prettierrc --write '**/*.{js|jsx}'`
3. one by one, created a new entry in my `.eslintrc` to set the blocking error to `'warn'`; e.g., added `'no-param-reassign': 'warn'` (something I often do in my `.reduce` routines).

All in all, the process took me about 5 min.

This got me to a place where I could compile the app whilst giving me time to work through/prioritize what makes sense in this `fast-refresh`, non-ejected CRA, Eslint v7 version of the app.

- E

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem

this problem have a open issue in CRA (version 4.0) on [github](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9887)

I found a temporary solution for this

1. delete `node_modules`
2. change `React-Scripts` version form `4.0.0` to `3.4.4`
3. add this `SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true` into `.env` file
4. run `npm install`
5. hope enjoy :)

*PS : if `.env` file dose not exist on your project you can create that in root folder*

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error and here is what worked for me.

Along with the error I got the following suggestions in the terminal when I wanted to create an app.

```
  1. Delete package-lock.json (not package.json!) and/or yarn.lock in your project folder.
  2. Delete node_modules in your project folder.
  3. Remove "eslint" from dependencies and/or devDependencies in the package.json file in your project folder.
  4. Run npm install or yarn, depending on the package manager you use.
```

I did all 3 above. Then I did the following-

```
I uninstalled eslint
npm uninstall -g create-react-app //uninstall create react app
npm install eslint --save-dev //reinstalled eslint
npm install -g yarn //installed yarn because I was using npm
used yarn to install create react app
yarn create-react-app nameofapp //used yarn to create a new app
```

when I did npm start, it worked as it seems like yarn was working to patch up/work through the problems.

I had to do a bit of trial and error here but finally it worked. I am no expert so did not really understand what exactly happened under the hood but this worked for me as yarn took care of the eslint problem.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the third last line in your `.eslintrc.json` file

```
"no-unused-vars": "error"
```

with

```
"no-unused-vars": "warn"
```

I expect that change to result in a warning instead of an error.

Don't forget to restart your text editor or IDE!

**Disclaimer**
From what I can read in your question, I believe my tip should help.
But I haven't tried it myself.

Comment: Users can always leave comments if they want to ask you for clarifications on your answer, or to provide additional information. You don't need to mention that explicitly in an answer, since it's assumed.

Answer (score -1):

since `eslint-loader` is now deprecated and `eslint-webpack-plugin` is now used in create-react-app check the [docs](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/eslint-webpack-plugin), I was able to solve a the issue by adding two options to the `eslint-webpack-plugin`

after ejecting your react app, add these options to the `ESLintPlugin` options:

```
      new ESLintPlugin({
        // Plugin options
        extensions: ['js', 'mjs', 'jsx', 'ts', 'tsx'],
        formatter: require.resolve('react-dev-utils/eslintFormatter'),
        eslintPath: require.resolve('eslint'),
        context: paths.appSrc,
        failOnError: false,  <== `This one`
        emitWarning: true,  <== `And this one`
        // ESLint class options
        cwd: paths.appPath,
        resolvePluginsRelativeTo: __dirname,
        baseConfig: {
          extends: [require.resolve('eslint-config-react-app/base')],
          rules: {
            ...(!hasJsxRuntime && {
              'react/react-in-jsx-scope': 'error'
            })
          }
        }
      })
```

Comment: What if you don't want to eject your react app because ejecting is a [one way operation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/available-scripts/#npm-run-eject)

Comment: I solved it without ejecting, I answered on this post. It's just and env variable for prod or dev @ThomasKagan

Answer (score -1):

You can add two properties to ESLintPlugin method, inside node_modules\react-scripts\config\webpack.config.js for your project.

failOnError: false,
emitWarning: true,

```
 new ESLintPlugin({
        // Plugin options
        extensions: ['js', 'mjs', 'jsx', 'ts', 'tsx'],
        formatter: require.resolve('react-dev-utils/eslintFormatter'),
        eslintPath: require.resolve('eslint'),
        context: paths.appSrc,
        cache: true,
        failOnError: false,
        emitWarning: true,
        // ESLint class options
        cwd: paths.appPath,
```

[image]

Comment: you shouldn't really just update the config in your node_modules folder. It will just revert every time you `npm install`.

Answer (score -1):

in module.rules modify following rule  to have

```
failOnError: false,
emitWarning: true,
```

```
{
          test: /\.(js|mjs|jsx)$/,
          enforce: 'pre',
          use: [
            {
              options: {
                formatter: require.resolve('react-dev-utils/eslintFormatter'),
                eslintPath: require.resolve('eslint'),
                failOnError: false,
                emitWarning: true,
              },
              loader: require.resolve('eslint-loader'),
            },
          ],
          include: paths.appSrc,
        }
```

Comment: how are you going to use this without a webpack config?

Comment: havent thought of that, i have react-scripts ejected.

Comment: then i think CI=false is best solution.