# How to prevent failing to compile on CRA when eslint errors

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, eslint

I installed the new react/CRA versions. Right now when I have eslint errors the whole page blows and CRA fails to compile.

Sometimes I make some small test or debug something in the flow, and don't want CRA to fail the running only because of 1-2 intentional eslint errors.

Is there a possibility only to display the errors in the console, but not to fail to compile?

If it fails the npm run build it is okay.

Thanks and best regards

Comment: You could check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/66156990/10138279