# Reactjs error: parsing-error,unexpected token

Tags: html, reactjs, webpack, eslint

i just created a project by creat-react-app,when i opened index.html then it reported me an error.

````
> 1 | <!DOCTYPE html>
    | ^
  2 | <html lang="en">
  3 |
  4 | <head>eslint```

It may be caused by some previous configurations of eslint.
I would appreciate it if you could tell me the reason
````

Comment: i created it on vscode

Comment: Refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64518226/my-create-react-app-is-failing-to-compile-due-to-eslint-error