# React: Errors in tags and imports in new project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code

I have created a new react project in VS and I've got some "errors" in "imports" statements and "" tags.

I have started the project and watch it in a browser without any problems and I have made a build of the project too.

Here you've got a pair of images to see what happen.

[image][image]

My package.json is:

```
{
  "name": "front-end",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.15.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "jshint": "^2.13.1"
  }
}
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Isn't this article a solution for you maybe: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64630234/5506730

Comment: @gazdagergo Finally, it doesn't work to me :( I have created the .env file and created the flag but it doesn't work to me :(

Comment: Anyway... it seems like an eslint babel error to me. Btw. did you try nextjs? I'd absolutely recommend to switch from `create-react-app` to `npx create-next-app`. You will love it.

Comment: @gazdagergo I have not tried next.js. I will try it!!! Thanks for the recommendation!!!