# I get this error: "'handleDelete' is not defined" after run `npm run build`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

Why did I get this error(after `npm run build`)? While `handleDelete` is defined.

[image]

BlogList.js:

```
const BlogList = ({blogs, title, handleDelete}) => {
    return(
        <div className="blog-list">
            <h2>{title}</h2>
            {blogs.map((blog) => (
                <div className="blog-preview" key={blog.id}>
                    <h2>{blog.title}</h2>
                    <p>Written by {blog.author}</p>
                    <button onClick={() => handleDelete(blog.id)}>
                        Delete Blog
                    </button>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}

export default BlogList;
```

Home.js

```
import BlogList from "./BlogList";

const Home = () =>{
    const [blogs, setBlogs] = useState([
        { title: 'My new website', body: 'lorem ipsum...', author: 'mario', id: 1 },
        { title: 'Welcome party!', body: 'lorem ipsum...', author: 'yoshi', id: 2 },
        { title: 'Web dev top tips', body: 'lorem ipsum...', author: 'mario', id: 3 }
    ]);

    const handleDelete = (id) => {
        const newBlogs = blogs.filter(blog => blog.id !== id);
        setBlogs(newBlogs);
    }
    return(
        <div className="Home">
            <BlogList blogs={blogs} title="All Blogs" handleDelete={handleDelete} />
        </div>
    );
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: It's an Eslint warning, not an error, but that warning stops the build. I suggest, since your code works, just ignoring the rule for that line/file, or switching off the rule altogether, or [look at the details of this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64518226/my-create-react-app-is-failing-to-compile-due-to-eslint-error).

Comment: I don't see any error in the code. It ran for me. here is the sandbox https://codesandbox.io/live/05e07ae8a67

Comment: @charchit Yes, it does not give an error to me too, when I run `npm start`. But when I run `npm run build` I get this.

Comment: Can you provide the full code (like github) because I am able to run npm build without errors.

Comment: @charchit Thanks a lot. https://github.com/arman-ebrahimi/Complete-react-tutorial

Comment: @ArmanEbrahimi I was successfully able to execute `npm run build` with the provided github code.  The app is running without any errors.  It might be related to your os. you should try again

Comment: @charchit But I get this error again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245252/discussion-between-charchit-and-arman-ebrahimi).